# eclipse accurev plugin

Tags: eclipse, version-control, eclipse-plugin, accurev

I've been working on a project in Eclipse that uses the Accurev VCS. Until now, I've been switching from Eclipse to the Accurev GUI in order to perform VCS commands.

As you can imagine, this quickly becomes tiresome, so I recently installed the Accurev Eclipse plugin. However, when I open the "sychronize" view or the Accurev perspective it's clear that the current project is not recognised as an Accurev project. How do I connect my project to Accurev within Eclipse such that I can use the plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the project and select Team -> Share Project. You should see your source control system listed there. How it works from here is dependent on your source control system and its plugin. I am not familiar with Accurev, so cannot help you there.